# Probability a Brownian Motion intersects a curve without Monte Carlo

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, monte-carlo

Suppose we wave a Brownian Motion $B_t$ on the interval [0,1] and I would like to compute the probability that in intersects a given curve of the following type:

$f(-1)=-\infty $,   $f(1)=0$ and f is strictly increasing.

E.g  $f$ could be  $\displaystyle{-\frac{1}{x} +1}$.

Is there a way I could to this type or problems without Monte-Carlo methods i.e 
maybe arrive at a PDE or an integral ?

Clarification: A Brownian motion in the interval  [0,1] is a random function $B_t$: $[0,1] -> \mathbb{R} $. Such that $B_0=0$ and the increments are independent normal distributed such that $B_{t_1}-B_{t_2}$ $=N(0,t_1-t_2) $ for  $t_1>t_2$.

Comment: For the $f$ you gave, $f(-1) = 2$. Also, could you expand on what you mean by Brownian motion on the interval $[0,1]$. Maybe is standard terminology, in which case I apologise. Do you mean a 1D Brownian motion on said interval, boncing from the walls at $0$ and $1$?

Comment: A Brownian motion in the interval  [0,1] is a random function $B_t$: $[0,1] -> \mathbb{R} $. Such that $B_0=0$ and the increments are independent normal distributed such that $B_{t_1}-B_{t_2}$ $=N(0,t_1-t_2) $ for  $t_1>t_2$. Also $f(-1)$ makes no sense here since we only look at $[0,1]$

Comment: I think the other commentor was asking what the boundary conditions are, i.e. what happens when the process hits 0 or 1 (which is rather necessary knowledge). Incidentally, if you don't want to use Monte Carlo, what about solving the Fokker-Planck equation associated to the process?

Comment: I meant the Brownian motion is defined between times 0 and 1, if it hits 0 or one it has no importance  i.e if $B_t=0$ or $B_t=1$ for some t.